# Django somehow accesses the static files even after i had deleted the whole static folder

Tags: django, static, django-static, django-statistics

I am new to Django, I had placed the static files in the project level `static` folder and even in multiple applications inside the `app/static/app` directory. Everything was working fine until I decided to delete few of the static files. The project is surprisingly accessing the deleted static files i.e `images` and `stylesheets`. I even had deleted both the `static` and the `staticfiles` folders and it still would access the static files that I had placed in these folders.
Following is a code snippet from my `setting.py` file.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    ('accounts', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'accounts', 'static')),
    ('transport_resources', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'transport_resources', 'static')),]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Whatever I do with those static files, it still manages to access the old and even deleted files. I am assuming that it keeps a cache of the files that we had used previously if this is the case, how can we clear that cache. Thanks!

Comment: Are you in debug or production?

Comment: Yes setting.py says Debug=True

Comment: And have you restarted your server? Ran `collectstatic`?

Comment: yeah. did that. it didn't work

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the new files to something other than the old file names did work.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem
even after I deleted and run the
$ python manage.py collectstatic --clear it still manages to access the file

this is because the browser is caching static files

open it on another browser/incognito window

when I used another port problem solved

```
$ python manage.py runserver 9000
```